# Grab first n rows from a streamlit Interactive Dataframe to a list back to the main programme after it is sorted from the user

Tags: python, pandas, list, streamlit

Hi i am looking for a way to return first n rows from a given column of an interactive Streamlit Data Frame to a list as:
list = df['name'].head(n).tolist()
and then execute a function to the Streamlit app using this list.
Streamlit has a st data editor experimental app but i cant figure out from the examples provided how i can do this task.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a concise example to answer your question, hope it can help you solve your specific case. Please add comments with precisions if this is not enough.
All it does is display a dataframe, extract some elements and put them into a list, and make streamlit display this list.

```py
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"name": ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"], "age": [25, 30, 35], "gender": ["female", "male", "male"]})

st.dataframe(df2)


def create_list(df_, nb_rows):
    return df_["age"].head(nb_rows).to_list()


first_n_elements = create_list(df2, 2)

st.text(" ".join([str(i) for i in first_n_elements]))
```

Comment: Hi and thanks..This code does not account that the data frame in the streamlit app is interactive and that the user can sort the columns by clicking on the name of the columns..so when i sort a column the first n elements rearange and the list has to update and match the sorting and rerun the command with the new list and so on!